# Unable to use standard Vue plugin with Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, draggable, vue-component, nuxt.js

Trying to get the Dragabilly Vue plugin to work with my Nuxt app: **https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-draggabilly**

I've used the usual approach that has worked with similar plugins but I don't have the depth of knowledge to crack this one. I am adding into my nuxt config file:

```
plugins: [ { src: '~/plugins/vue-draggabilly.js', ssr: false } ]
```

That file includes this code:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueDraggabilly from 'vue-draggabilly'

Vue.use(VueDraggabilly)
```

However, I get the following error and I'm not able to use:

***vue-draggabilly.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined***

This refers to this line in the plugin:

```
exports.install = function (Vue, options) { ....
```

It is a usual vuew plugin package, but I'm not sure how to get it to work with nuxt.  Any help very greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I see a warning:

> warning  in ./plugins/vue-draggabilly.js
>
> 4:8-22 "export 'default' (imported as 'VueDraggabilly') was not found in 'vue-draggabilly'

I don't know the best answer, but this seems to work:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import * as VueDraggabilly from 'vue-draggabilly'

Vue.use(VueDraggabilly)
```

Comment: Thanks for looking @paul-tsai.  Still no luck for me though I'm afraid - I get the same error using your 'import * ' code above:

_: exports is not defined
    at Object../node_modules/vue-draggabilly/vue-draggabilly.js (vue-draggabilly.js:3)_